# Factory pattern using generics

Tags: java, spring, generics, factory-pattern

I would like to build a class that caches classes of type CachedObject using Map.

```
public class CachedObject {
    protected Long id;
    public CachedObject(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Below is the factory class.

```
public class CachedObjectFactory<T extends CachedObject> {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CachedObjectFactory.class);
private Map<Long, T> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();

public T get(Class<T> type, Long id) throws CachedObjectInstantiationException {
    T cachedObject = cacheMap.get(id);
    try {
        if(cachedObject == null) {
            cachedObject = type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(id);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new CachedObjectInstantiationException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return cachedObject;
}

}
```

I have a class that extends CacheableObject as below:

```
@Component
class X extends CachedObject {
   
    public X(Long id) {
           super(id);
       }
       ....

}
```

When I try to create an instance of class X that extends CachedObject using the get method in the factory as below: (please note that cachedObjectFactory is autowired using Spring)

```
@Component
class Y extends CachedObject {

       CachedObjectFactory<CachedObject> cachedObjectFactory;
       Y(Long id, CachedObjectFactory cachedObjectFactory) {
          super(id);
          this.cachedObjectFactory = cachedObjectFactory;
       } 
    
       public void someMethod() {
          X x = cachedFactory.get(X.class, id);
       }

}
```

I get the compile time error "The method get(Class, Long) in the type CachedObjectFactory is not applicable for the arguments (Class,
Long)". How should I instantiate an object X using the factory method?

Comment: You seem to be confusing `CachedObject` and `CacheableObject`

Comment: @tgdavies, sorry my fault. Just fixed it.

Comment: cachedObjectFactory in Y is a raw type.

Comment: Right. That's also a typo. I am defining in the actual class as CachedObjectFactory<CachedObject> cachedObjectFactory;

Comment: Please post your actual code, otherwise us reading it is a bit pointless.

Comment: My actual code has lot of biz logic that I tried to simplify and along the way I introduced typos. It looks correct in its current version I posted. The problem is that I am unable to get an instance from the factory though the factory class compiles without any issue.

Comment: Are you using a single `CachedObjectFactory` for all your `CachedObject` subclasses? So the ids are unique across all subclasses?

Comment: Yes, I am using single factory. I am using userId across the board and hence is unique.

Comment: So an instance of X can't possibly have the same id as any instance of Y? (incidentally, I'm not sure Y should extend `CachedObject`, as it doesn't have a constructor which takes just an id.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a field as `CachedObjectFactory<CachedObject>` doesn't really mean anything -- the parameter already has `CachedObject` as an upper bound.

You can get your code to compile by changing you factory to look like this:

```java
public class CachedObjectFactory {

        private Map<Long, Object> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();

        public <T extends CachedObject> T get(Class<T> type, Long id) {
            T cachedObject = (T)cacheMap.get(id);
            try {
                if(cachedObject == null) {
                    cachedObject = type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(id);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
            }
            return cachedObject;
        }
    }
```

As you are using your factory for many classes, making it generic doesn't really make sense.

Of course if two instances of different subclasses of `CachedObject` have the same id you'll get a runtime `ClassCastException`.

Comment: You are right. The userId being used as the key is not unique which would render this factory useless. I may have to skip the factory in this case though there will be lot of redundant code which I was trying to avoid in first place. Thanks.

Comment: You could make your `map` key a composite of the `Class` and `id`.

Comment: You mean use the hash code of the class and the user id?

Comment: You'd need to create a class which had the Class and id as fields, and implemented `hashCode` and `equals`. You can also look at Spring caching -- whether that suits you depends on where you create your cacheable instances.